# How to make this script dynamic

Tags: javascript

I am using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var defaultnoimage="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png";
  var maxresults=14;
  var splittercolor="none";
  var relatedpoststitle="Related Results";
</script>
```

As you can see it has a variable that lets me give a name to the results, in this case I have used Related Results. This code is used once at the back and in that way it used by my every page. So e-g if I change it to More Results it will changed everywhere on all pages. I don't want it like this, I want to be able to give a different name to every page like on one it is like 'More Images Results' while on 2nd it is something else. 
you can see a demo here at this page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-slider.html

Comment: You can use query string parameter and send the required text to show.

Comment: What is your server side language?

Comment: It is html and I am not using server actually its blogger a free service :P

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess as to what you are asking, as I find your wording a little confusing...

When I need to inject code from a server lang/env into my client side code, I like to use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) in JS, with my server lang doing its output in the input param area.

So, in PHP (as I don't know what your server lang is) I would do this:

```
<?php
$relatedpoststitle = 'Related Results'; //or whatever you need it to be for the current execution
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function (global, relatedpoststitle) {
    global.defaultnoimage = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png';
    global.maxresults = 14;
    global.splittercolor = 'none';
    global.relatedpoststitle = relatedpoststitle;
  }(
    window,
    "<?php echo $relatedpoststitle; ?>"
  ));
</script>
```

This lets me consolidate all of my server code into one small space instead of intermixing code/logic from different langs/envs.

Comment: well I am using html, not php so what would I do in html ?

Comment: I dunno.  I think I must have misunderstood your question.